# How do I removed accordions in the advanced search

Tags: search, templates, advanced-search

My charity needs a custom address field, rather than the address field that comes with civicrm. This is mostly set up, but there is one issue we have.

We have removed the fields from the advanced search, but the accordion for 'address' fields is still  there. I have tried going through the templates, but I have no idea where to find it to remove it...

[image]

Here is a screenshot that shows what I mean. How can I remove this 'Address fields' accordian/ where is it located in the files.

(I would also like to rename the custom fields accordion, but I'm hopeful that this would be in the same place )

Answer (score 3):

Unchecking the box in the image below for each field in your custom data set ensures it is not searchable. If no fields within the custom data set are searchable, the "accordion" is removed from the advanced search. If just one is searchable, then the accordion appears.

Just confirmed this with 5.10.3.

As for your second question, if you want to rename "Custom Fields" to something else, you can do that using CiviCRM's word replacement tool. Go to Administer > Customize Data & Screens > Word Replacement.

[image]

Comment: Its not my custom data that I want gone, its the address field that already exists within civicrm

Comment: I n my screenshot the "address" accordion is extended, but there are *no* fields in it.